# Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'cordova.file.documentsDirectory')

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

When run in mobile device i get this error i was 3 days ago searching, how do fixed this issue?

Ionic v: 1.7 
npm v:   5.7.1 
Node v:  v6.13.0 
cordova plugin ls

```
cordova-fabric-plugin 1.1.10 "cordova-fabric-plugin"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 0.10.0 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-camera-preview 0.9.0 "cordova-plugin-camera-preview"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.4.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.2 "DatePicker"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7 "Device"
cordova-plugin-device-orientation 1.0.7 "Device Orientation"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 2.0.2 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.4 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 1.4.2 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-sqlite-2 1.0.4 "SQLitePlugin"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.3 "File"
```

in My code

```
 var documentDirectory = (ionic && ionic.Platform && ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) ? cordova.file.externalDataDirectory : cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(documentDirectory, function (fs) {}, handleError);
```

Comment: did you wait for the `deviceready` event to set this variable?

Comment: Yes i wait, when the function is called is in callback from login success

Comment: i try adding timeout for 6000 ms but i get same error

Comment: are you testing on a real phone/emulator? It's possible it comes as `undefined` when you test in browser with `ionic serve`

Comment: Only virtual device ios D: